# MVC 3 HiddenField not rendering base 64 data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC 3 (RAZOR) for my Web Application.

I have a simple "edit" view that deals with an employee record (e.g. First Name, Last Name, DOB, etc), but some of the data is sensitive and encrypted. The sensitive data is encrypted and converted into base 64 string. The sensitive data is not editable in the edit view, but is passed to a hidden field to "preserve it" so that it's not lost in the postback if other fields on the employee record need to be edited.

I think that because this data is base 64, it will not render in a hidden field - perhaps it's an MVC 3 security thing. I should also mention that this property is marked as Required on my model. So it must be re-populated in order to post back.

Is there a special attribute that I need to put on this property to tell MVC that it's okay to use in a hidden field? Any other ideas?

In RAZOR, my hidden field declaration looks like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SomeBase64String)
```

In HTML, it gets rendered as such:

```
<input style="margin-right: 5px;" id="SomeBase64String" name="SomeBase64String" value="" type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="SomeBase64String is required.">
```

An example of the base 64 string might be:

```
OW0iSdFXUqaUT82qjqaG5w==
```

Inside the Edit (GET) controller action, I have the following:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Employee employee;

            if (id == 0)
            {
                employee = Employee.CreateNew();
            }
            else
            {
                employee = _employeeDatabaseAccess.GetEmployeeById(id);

                //employee.SomeBase64String is already set. it's stored in the db...
            }

            return View(employee);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the corresponding property on your view model inside the controller action before rendering the view:

```
model.SomeBase64String = ...
return View(model);
```

But I would recommend you not bothering with any encryptions. The correct way to handle this is to not pass this information to the view at all if the user is not supposed to edit it. And then in your POST controller action simply use the id of the record to read this information from wherever you read it initially (I guess you are using some data store or something).

You should pass to the view only information that the user is supposed to view and edit. Passing sensitive information is like asking for trouble.

Comment: It is. model.SomeBase64String is set correctly right before it's passed to the view.

Comment: I should also mention that if I set a breakpoint on the last line in your statements and set the value to a friendlier value. It renders just fine.

Comment: If `model.SomeBase64String` is set then this should work. Make sure that this property is of type string. There is no reason why the `Html.HiddenFor` helper will render simple strings but skip more complex strings.

Comment: Me neither, this should work. Is this property assignment happening inside a `[HttpPost]` action?

Comment: Hmm, that looks very weird indeed. Sorry but I have no idea why this doesn't work. Could you provide a sample allowing to reproduce the issue? With a sample model and hardcoded value of the base64 property without using any databases, ...

Comment: Certainly. Let me get back with you and I will provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I created a sample MVC project as Darin suggested and verified that a Base 64 String could be rendered in a hidden field. No problem. There must be a problem in my application.